# Get value from data set

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

this is the result of `console.log('<?php print_r($graph) ?>');`

```
{"H10":"98.25","I10":"59.00","H17":"59.26","I17":"26.10","H22":"0.00","I22":"1.84","H40":"0.00","I40":"0.00","H2":"14.88","I2":"8.80" }
```

I want to get these values by key from java script, how to get this values one by one?

I have tried
`console.log('<?php print_r($graph['H10']) ?>');` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said "in JavaScript," but your attempt to do it is in PHP. Remember that the PHP runs on the *server*, and determines what gets sent to the browser; the JavaScript code (in this case) runs on the *client* in the browser.

If you want to access this data in JavaScript, first, output it into your JavaScript code as data.

It's not clear what `$graph` contains in your PHP code, a string or an associative array.

**If** it's an associative array, use `json_encode` and `echo`:

```
var data = <?php echo(json_encode($graph)); ?>;
```

**But**, I suspect it's a string in JSON format based on the fact that what you tried didn't give you `"98.25"`; in which case, just echo it:

```
var data = <?php echo($graph); ?>;
```

One of those will send this to the browser:

```
var data = {"H10":"98.25","I10":"59.00","H17":"59.26","I17":"26.10","H22":"0.00","I22":"1.84","H40":"0.00","I40":"0.00","H2":"14.88","I2":"8.80"};
```

Then, in your JavaScript code on the browser, you have an object with property names like `H10` and such:

```
console.log(data.H10);
// or
console.log(data["H10"]);
```

Live example:

```js
var data = {"H10":"98.25","I10":"59.00","H17":"59.26","I17":"26.10","H22":"0.00","I22":"1.84","H40":"0.00","I40":"0.00","H2":"14.88","I2":"8.80"};

console.log(data.H10);
// or
console.log(data["H10"]);
```

If you want to loop through all the properties, you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of the property names, and loop through them:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + data[name]);
});
```

Live example:

```js
var data = {"H10":"98.25","I10":"59.00","H17":"59.26","I17":"26.10","H22":"0.00","I22":"1.84","H40":"0.00","I40":"0.00","H2":"14.88","I2":"8.80"};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + data[name]);
});
```

Comment: great explanation.